# Is it still true that Swift Packages don't support custom build configurations

Tags: swift-package-manager

I see comments that this is not supported but they are over a year old. Has this changed with the latest Swift and Xcode 13?

Apparently you can do this in the targets section

```
targets: [
        .target(
            name: "MyLibrary",
            swiftSettings: [
                .define("MYCONDITIONVARIABLE", .when(configuration: .debug)),
                ]),
```

but, I would like to specify other build schemes other than debug and release.

Comment: Still didn't change.

Comment: Latest reference I've seen is [here](https://forums.swift.org/t/build-swiftpm-dependencies-using-custom-build-configuration/70065). But that's not positive.